# Do percentage bonuses stack?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I currently have three items that give a percentage bonus to Magicka Regen:

- Archmage's Robes: 100%
- Morokei: 100%
- Ring of Resurgence: 80%

Are these bonuses stacking?  Or should I drop the ring and one of the others because they're superfluous?  How does bonus stacking work in Skyrim?

Comment: 280% Magicka Regen.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes the bonus's stack,though during combat they do recharge just a little more slowly then when out of combat but with higher stats like your using you won't notice the slow down really. It's a very good way to have an almost limitless supply of magicka.
the stacking works different for magicka regen as opposed to say weapons and such.
here are a few links to other such stacking...

[How does multiplying damage work in Skyrim?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/38485/15734) for damage multipliers

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/38363/15734 carry weight speech and such

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim_talk:Enchanting broad base

hope this helped

Comment: Does the recharge *actually* happen more slowly during combat, or does it just seem so because you're not recharging while casting?

Comment: @Iszi It is noticeably slower in combat. You can test this by draining your Magika completely, noting how fast it recharges, drain it again, then before letting it recharge completely enter combat. You'll see the regen rate immediately drop off.

Answer (score 6):

I'll specifically address the bounty comments.

> Are there differences between stacking perks, stacking enchantments, and stacking a combination of the two?

Yes.

Perks stack multiplicatively with themselves, so for example the "Agile Defender 5" perk, which increases Light Armor rating by 100%, when combined with "Custom Fit", which increases Light Armor rating by 25% when wearing a full set, will result in a 250% total increase in Light Armor defense.

On the other hand, enchantments and potions use the same effect, which you can see under the "Active effects" tab in the "Magic" menu, and they will all stack additively with themselves. So for example a "Fortify One-Handed" enchantment with 20% strength, when combined with a "Potion of Fortify One-Handed" with 40% strength, will result in a 60% total increase in One-Handed weapon damage.

These two categories stack multiplicatively with each other, so drinking a "Potion of Fortify Archery" with 50% strength while having the "Overdraw 5" perk, which increases Bow damage by 100%, will result in a 300% total increase in Bow damage.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK bonus stacking in Skyrim should be additive.
For example if you have x Magicka regeneration rate and both +50%, +70%, you'll end up with x*(120%) so x*(1 + 1.2).

This game should *not* be like WoW were stacking of % based is *usually* multiplicative (i.e. 50% + 70% in multiplicative is 1.5*1.7 = 2.55).

Hope this help,
Cheers

Comment: Btw, this means that in case of magic cost reduction you could get 0% cost (basically no mana needed). If this would have been multiplicative you'd never be able to reach 0% cost.