# What is the speed increase of the 'sleek' armor mod?

Tags: fallout-4

For my stealth build character, I'm weighing the options of a few of the available leg armor mods. The [Sleek](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_armor_mods) mod has the description of `Increased Movement Speed while sneaking`. Unlike the [Sprinter's](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Legendary_armor_effects) legendary effect, which states it gives a 10% increase, Sleek does not provide a value to the increase in sneak movement speed.

How much faster does Sleek make you? Also, does having both leg armors modded with Sleek stack the speed increase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sleek mods each add 5 to the actor value Mod_StealthMove_AV [AVIF:00245BEB] and apply the Stealth Move enchantment (00245BDE), which in turn uses the actor value to fortify (add) 5 to the actor speed mult (which is usually at 1) to result in 1.05 (5 % increase). Its condition is "if Mod_StealthMove_AV equal to 5." It also fortifies (adds) 5 to the actor speed mult "if Mod_StealthMove_AV equal to 10."

Obviously, Mod_StealthMove_AV will only either equal to 5 or equal to 10, so you don't get the benefits of both effects in just one enchantment.

If the game allows an enchantment to get applied twice (I assume it does, going off of [this answer here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37172/if-multiple-items-have-the-same-enchantment-does-the-bonus-stack)), then the effect will stack to 1.10 (10%).

(EDIT)
After testing ingame I can confirm that the bonuses do indeed stack, and that the speedmult goes from 1 to 1.05 with one mod and then to 1.10 with two mods. Should have just tested first and left out the technical stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I think the technical stuff is helpful to show the research of the answer. I actually just ran across [a mod](http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/5808/?) that _supposedly_ fixed an issue where it seemed 2 sleek modifiers **did not** stack. I'm not sure if the mod really uncovered a bug, if it got fixed in a subsequent patch (I didn't see it anywhere in the patch notes), but it's good to know that having 2 stack properly really is getting the desired effect.

Comment: No problem! Looking at his mod he assumed what I'd originally wrote here, that having the effect 5 and then 5 again at 10 meant it wouldn't stack, but because the effect is added twice with two enchantments it does (again, I tested by sneaking and typing player.getav speedmult so I know it does indeed stack).